# Creation of a temporary table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, temp-tables

I'm trying to create a temporary table in Postgres (to speed up joining, as there will be a lot of similar queries throughout a session). The SQL that will be called at the beginning of a session is the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE extended_point AS
SELECT (
  point.id,
  local_location,
  relative_location,
  long_lat,
  region,
  dataset,
  region.name,
  region.sub_name,
  color,
  type)
FROM point, region, dataset
WHERE point.region = region.id AND region.dataset = dataset.id;
```

The tables point has the columns id::int, region::int, local_location::point, relative_location::point, long_lat:point (longitude, latitude).

Region has the columns id::int, color::int, dataset::int, name::varchar, sub_name::varchar.

Dataset has the columns id::int, name::varchar, type:varchar.

When this is run, I get the error message: [25P02] ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block.

As a side, the commands are executed in PyCharm, and is part of a Python project.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The error means that some statement *before* the one you are running had an error. You need to rollback the current transaction before you can proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an important difference between these two queries:

```
select 1, 'abc';
select (1, 'abc');
```

The first query returns one row with **two** columns with values 1 and 'abc'. The second one returns a row with **one** column of pseudo-type *record* with value (1, 'abc').

Your query tries to create a table with one column of pseudo-type *record*. This is impossible and should end with

```
ERROR: column "row" has pseudo-type record
SQL state: 42P16
```

Just remove brackets from your query.
As a_horse stated, [25P02] ERROR does not apply to the query in question.

Btw, my advice: never use keywords as table/column names.

Comment: What would you recommend instead?

Comment: My tables have plural names. For columns I often use more descriptive names, eg. *client_name*, *product_type*, etc. Sometimes I try to find synonyms if necessary. In addition, I use the important principle: all primary keys have unique names across the database (*client_id*, *product_id*, etc).